# Parsing HTML and pulling down a drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing, drop-down-menu

I am writing some code that connects to a website, and using C#, and System.IO, reads the html file into my application, and then I continue to parse it.

What I am wanting to do now is, there is a drop down (combobox) on this site, that has 2 static values.  I am wanting to have my code pick the 2nd option in the combo box and then parse the resulting html on the post back.

Any Ideas?

Ya the 2 selects are always the same.

Spamming software? Uh... No. It parses a video game website for player stats and I have full permission from the vendor to do so.

Yes I agree about the webservices, and they dont exist. I have already written the HTML parser and it works great. However, I need to pop this drop down for more data

Comment: Can you guarantee the content of the page, i.e. does it only have 1 <select> or at least have an id?

Comment: Sounds like form spamming software to me...

Comment: A better option to pursue would be for them to open a web service for you to digest the player stats. HTML parsing can be troublesome if you dont control the html you are parsing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the code looks like this:

```
What color is your favorite?: <br/>
<form method="post" action="post.php">
        <select name="color">
            <option>AliceBlue</option>
            <option>AntiqueWhite</option>
            <option>Aqua</option>
        </select><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You would want to POST to post.php the argument "color" with the value "Aqua" (or whatever select value you want).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and the [HtmlAgilitypPack.AddOns.FormProcessor](http://apps.ultravioletconsulting.com/projects/uvcwebtransform/docs/files.html) for that.